# How to create float charts with chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I tried creating float charts with chartjs but it does not seem to work. I tried copying the same example as they have http://pravopys.net/chartjs/samples/charts/bar/vertical.html but mine does not render at all or throw any errors.

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Population (millions)",
                    data: [
                        [-2, 5],
                        [-20, 70],
                        [30, 80]
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    type: "bar"
                }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: { display: false },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
          }
        }
    });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The example shows the data structure for the dataset being used exactly how I'm using it. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Plunker link: http://www.plnkr.co/edit/bD1MgVvjuq7B4RM5Qcmh?p=preview

Comment: You  have to wait for the release of version 2.9. It's not implemented yet. (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4120#issuecomment-494304289, https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Or you can look for workaround (you get a few when you google).

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you. I figured a workaround also. Version 2.7.3 works with this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need a 2d context to draw the chart on. Here's a working example:

[image: Edit delicate-rgb-mms78]

Do these 2 changes in your code:

### HTML

```
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

### Javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, ...)
```

**Source:** https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. I also created a plunker http://www.plnkr.co/edit/bD1MgVvjuq7B4RM5Qcmh?p=preview

Comment: Flatten your dataset's "data" attribute. See my example, or this corrected plunker: http://www.plnkr.co/edit/3qkfYJZwIkZzdrAbu1Lo?p=preview

Comment: But in that case that's not floating charts? in that case they all start from zero and go up and down depending on the data